# Issues with program that analyzes two urls and gets the list of shared words and how many times they appear in both pages

Tags: python

I'm getting many issues when trying to code a program that gets as input two urls (u1,u2) , decodes them in the variable enc (which is utf-8 most of the times) and gets the list of the same words of lenght k which occur in both pages and how many times they get repeated in url1 and url2. I was trying to write (in python 3.5) something like this:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
def com_url(u1, u2,enc, k):
        response = urlopen(u1)
        response2 = urlopen(u2)
        html = response.read().lower()
        html2 = response2.read().lower()
        lista= [x.encode(enc) for x in html]
        lista2= [x.encode(enc) for x in html2]
        lista_dec=lista.split()
        lista2_dec=lista2.split()
        dizionario= [lista.count(p) for p in lista_dec]
        dizionario2= [lista2.count(p) for p in lista2_dec]
        def sortFreqDict(freqdict):
                aux = [(freqdict[key], key) for key in freqdict]
                aux.sort()
                aux.reverse()
        dizord=sortFreqDict(dizionario)
        dizord2=sortFreqDict(dizionario2)
        def intersect(a, b):
                list(set(a) & set(b))
        elcom= intersect(dizord,dizord2)
        lista_elcom= elcom.split()
        a=0
        b=0
        c=0
        if len(lista_dec) > len(lista2_dec):
                for c in range(len(lista_dec)):
                        if k in [len(k) for k in lista_elcom]:
                                if lista_elcom[c] in dizord:
                                        a=a+1
                                        ris=lista_elcom[c]
                                if lista_elcom[c] in dizord2:
                                        b=b+1
                                        ris=lista_elcom[c]
                                if ris != 0:
                                        print(ris,a,b)
        else:
                for c in range(len(lista2_dec)):
                        if k in [len(k) for k in lista_elcom]:
                                if lista_elcom[c] in dizord:
                                        a=a+1
                                        ris=lista_elcom[c]
                                if lista_elcom[c] in dizord2:
                                        b=b+1
                                        ris=lista_elcom[c]
                                if ris != 0:
                                        print(ris,a,b)
```

at the moment I'm getting "AttributeError 'int' object has no attribute 'encode'"

Comment: What issues do you encounter?

Comment: @bli at the moment "AttributeError
    'int' object has no attribute 'encode'"

Comment: If this indeed corresponds to the lines where you use `encode` in the code you posted, it is rather strange. It means that your `x` is an `int` at some point. This implies that one of the `.read().lower()` calls returns a list of `int`s. I thought `lower()` would return a `string`.
You should edit your question to add the error message and tell what line of code it is associated with.

Comment: You should add a complete traceback when asking such questions.

Comment: traceback? @Jérôme

Comment: stack traceback: output, `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>` etc.

Comment: As i've written the only error I'm getting is this "error -> AttributeError
    'int' object has no attribute 'encode'"